# Synonym for not-suited

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

eg. Tropical climate not suited for huskies.

Comment: "Unsuitable for".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "tropical climate is inapt for huskies".

Inapt: not suitable for the situation:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inapt

Answer (score 1):

In this context you can replace 'not suited' by:1. unsuitable: not fitting or appropriate
2. unfit: something/someone is not of the desired quality or doesn't suit a chosen purpose
3. ill suited: inappropriate

Comment: This would be improved by including some dictionary definitions for the synonymous terms.